# TextInput vanishes inside ScrollView React Native

Tags: react-native, scrollview, textinput, react-native-scrollview, react-native-textinput

**Scenario:** I want to achieve a situation like the code shown below. Where there will be:

- A *multiline* `TextInput` with other components and the screen will be scrollable.
- I don't want the `TextInput` to be scrollable.

**Problem:** What happens is, after writing a certain amount of lines in the `TextInput`, the texts vanishes. I can still select the text and get suggestion in the keyboard. It's like the texts and the `TextInput` became transperant. After the `TextInput` reaches the height of the phone screen, this problem occurs.

Is this a bug of React-Native? or am I doing something wrong here?

**Note:** I'm using `"expo": "~40.0.0"`. Also, the code below is just to portrait the situation, not the actual code.

```js
return (
  <ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.block} />
    <View style={styles.block} />
    <TextInput
      value={content}
      onChangeText={setContent}
      placeholder="Start writing from here"
      multiline
    />
    <View style={styles.block} />
    <View style={styles.block} />
  </ScrollView>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  block: {
    height: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out any of following Workarounds:

- Enabling *scrollEnabled* on the *TextInput*
- Explicitly setting a height on the *TextInput* (eg. by dynamically measuring the contents)

> ```
> <ScrollView scrollEnabled style={{ marginTop: 100 }}>
>   <TextInput multiline placeholder="type here" scrollEnabled={true} />
> </ScrollView>
> ```

Comment: You can remove extra views and try giving height for TextInput directly.